# Selecting pixels in raster using polygon selection tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, raster-calculator, python-script-tool, rasterization

I want to reclassify landcover image manually with respect to online imagery. I am looking for a software/plugin/script to manually select raster pixels using polygon selection tool and could be able to enter new value.
Can you Please explain the process in QGIS?